# How to initialize a nested class in C#

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I am trying to initialize a nested class, Below is the nested class.

```
public class Msg
{        
    [JsonProperty("to")]
    public ToObj to { get; set; }   

    [JsonProperty("from")]
    public FromObj from { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("timestamp")]
    public string timestamp { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("message")]
    public MessageObj message { get; set; }
    public class ToObj
    {
        [JsonProperty("type")]
        public string type { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public string id { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("number")]
        public string number { get; set; }
    }

    public class FromObj
    {
        [JsonProperty("type")]
        public string type { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public string id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("number")]
        public string number { get; set; }

    }        
    }
```

Do I need to initialize each class every time? or any other way to initialize the nested class. Please let me know

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done like this :

```
var foo = new Msg
{
    to = new Msg.ToObj
    {
        type = "hello",
        id = "42",
        number = "69"
    },
    from = new Msg.FromObj
    {
        type = "World",
        id = "12",
        number = "7"
    }
    // other initializations...
};
```

However, I don't know why you use `public` nested class. Using separated class would be more appropriate. Plus, `From` and `To` seems to share exactly the same properties. They could be an unique class :

```
public class Obj
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string number { get; set; }
}

public class Msg
{        
    public Obj to { get; set; }   

    public Obj from { get; set; }

    public string timestamp { get; set; } 
}
```

And initialization :

```
var foo = new Msg
{
    to = new Obj
    {
        type = "hello",
        id = "42",
        number = "69"
    },

    from = new Obj
    {
        type = "World",
        id = "12",
        number = "7"
    }
    // other initializations...
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will consider your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

The nested class will behave like other class. If you want to initialize it you can do it on its constructor.